# Mysql: change a column to auto_increment with subquery to get max column id

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I just started working on mysql and have a question..
So I have a table tests that has columns like this
test_id
test_description
test_results

where test_id is BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

test_id column looks like

```
1
2
3
123
321
1293
1299
1300
1301
```

I'm trying to modify test_id, rename it, and set it auto increment based on the largest number in the column.

I could do this

```
ALTER TABLE tests CHANGE test_id result_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT=1302
```

So this would work, however, I want to set the auto increment to a variable, based on the largest number of test_id column.  I tried this

```
ALTER TABLE tests CHANGE test_id result_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT=(SELECT MAX(test_id) AS test_id FROM tests);
```

It is complaining about syntax errors around AUTO_INCREMENT.

Any idea if there's a way to do this?

Much appreciated

EDIT: JStephen's comment! I think it's working now. TY guys.

Comment: That's because you're mixing up DDL (which affect the schema) and DML (which look at the data). You'll probably have to use a stored procedure if you want to use pure mysql. Otherwise you can do that from your favourite client language.

Comment: I thought you do not need to specify the max number when setting a column to auto increment.

Comment: @JStephen would that just set to a counter of how many items in the column? anyways, I'm trying without a number now, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JStephen You are right! thanks, I'll clean up my queries and try it from scratch.  Again thank you.

Comment: just added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify the auto increment number it will automatically use the highest value when determining what the next increment will be.